# Listview custom adapter with imageview and buttons

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I tried to make a custom array adapter for my listview but the emulator crashes always and I can't see where my code is good and where it isn't.

The logcat says "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError" but I don't know how to solve. I tried to modify the studio.exe.vmoptions file or removing images (even if they are only 50x50) from the whole app, without any effort.

So I'll post my code, asking your help for making order in my app.

Thank you in advance!

```
public class MyClassAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Plate> {

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView Id;
    ImageView Image;
    TextView Name;
    TextView Description;
    TextView Type;
    TextView Cost;
    TextView Count;
    TextView Comment;
    Button Buttonup;
    Button Buttondown;
}

public MyClassAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Plate> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Plate item = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.Id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        viewHolder.Image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        viewHolder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        viewHolder.Cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.Count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        viewHolder.Buttonup = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_up);
        viewHolder.Buttondown = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_down);



        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    if (item!= null) {
        viewHolder.Id.setText(String.format("%d",item.getId()));
        viewHolder.Image.setImageURI(item.getImage());
        viewHolder.Name.setText(String.format("%s", item.getName()));
        viewHolder.Description.setText(String.format("%s", item.getDescription()));
        viewHolder.Name.setText(String.format("%s", item.getName()));
        viewHolder.Cost.setText(String.format("%s", item.getCost()));
        viewHolder.Count.setText(String.format("%d", item.getCount()));
        viewHolder.Buttonup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBHelper mydb= new DBHelper(getContext());
                mydb.AddPlate(item.getId());
                item.CountUp();
               //update viewholder.Count
            }
        });
        viewHolder.Buttondown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBHelper mydb= new DBHelper(getContext());
                mydb.RemovePlate(item.getId());
                item.CountDown();
                //update viewholder.Count
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

And here's a snippet of my code that calls the custom ArrayAdapter

```
        ArrayList<Plate> FullMenu;
        FullMenu = mydb.getPlates("Entrees");
        Plate p;
        int i;
        MyClassAdapter adapter = new MyClassAdapter(this,0,FullMenu);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (i=0; i < FullMenu.size(); i++) {
            p = FullMenu.get(i);
            adapter.add(p);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the setadapter

```
ArrayList<Plate> FullMenu;
    FullMenu = mydb.getPlates("Entrees");
    Plate p;
    int i;
    MyClassAdapter adapter = new MyClassAdapter(this,0,FullMenu);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    for (i=0; i < FullMenu.size(); i++) {
        p = FullMenu.get(i);
        adapter.add(p);
    }
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

also i dont think you need this, since you should read the data from the adapter itself

```
 for (i=0; i < FullMenu.size(); i++) {
        p = FullMenu.get(i);
        adapter.add(p);
    }
```

you can check this sample i have here for an adapter
https://github.com/juangdiaz/CoffeeApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/juangdiaz/coffeeapp/adapter/ListAdapter.java

and calling the adapter here
https://github.com/juangdiaz/CoffeeApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/juangdiaz/coffeeapp/fragments/CoffeeListFragment.java

let me know if this helps

Comment: I spent last 2 hours trying to set up the class Adapter and the error was in the call of the function. Now my little problem is that I can't call the viewholder inside the onclick method for updating in real-time the count, but I can try something now! :)

Comment: did it help the snipped i gave you? or are you still have the issue?

Comment: awesome! dont forget to give me the check mark that the question was answered :)

Comment: no way i could forget it, because it is the correct answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You should be **resize** **dynamically** your image, so you avoid a failure of memory.

[You can read this lesson](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

[And here you can see a simple example of its operation](https://github.com/JoseAngelManeiro/CustomListView/blob/master/src/joseangelmaneiro/customlistview/MainActivity.java)

Good luck!